# New tab pop-up first visit?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I want to show an informative little message in a new tab the first time someone enters my website. Thing is though, I can't make it work. Here's some code:

```
<html>
    <?php
        $cookie_name = "visited";
        $cookie_value = "1";
        if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {    

            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+60*60*24*365);

            echo "
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    function PopUp() {
                        window.open('http://example.com/information', '_blank');
                    }
                    PopUp();
                </script>
            ";
        }
    ?>
```

No cookie is set, but the pop-up keeps showing up every time I refresh the page. Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Try `setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+60*60*24*365, "/");`

Comment: There are quite a few different ways you can go about this. What if the user goes away and visit the site again next week, do you want the same popup to show ?

Comment: @aron9forever I did, but I edited it out for this post because I didn't know what the "/" actually did. Seemingly nothing for me!

Comment: @andre3wap No not really. I guess I'd just have to change the time for that, but since the cookie is not created.. :/

Comment: @JohnSmith did you manually check in your browser whether the cookie exists or not?. The `"/"` specifies the path and without it a cookie will not work. Please try adding it back again and changing `$cookie_name` to something else.

Comment: `setcookie()` must be called before any other browser output, i.e. before your `<html>` tag. otherwhise browser reject it.

Comment: Yeah @mitkosoft is right. Add the path back anyways because it will not work without it and move `<html>` under the php code.

Comment: @mitkosoft But will the javascript call work when it's not within `<html>`?

Comment: Ohhhhh I had to put it before the DOCTYPE declaration aswell! Christ. Thank you so much you two!

Comment: Yes, checking for cookie and setting a cookie are two different things. Just move setcookie part on very top.

Comment: @mitkosoft May I reward you with a "best answer"?

Comment: Sure, glad to help you, I've spent lot of time debugging such problem in my practice before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setcookie()` must be called before any other browser output, i.e. before your `<html>` tag. otherwhise browser reject it.